# Deploy Mono application without Framework on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, deployment, mono

I have a c#-program, that works well under Mono and on OSX, I also was able to create an app-directory for that program. Now I want to distribute it, but I don't want to force the user to install mono, since this is unusual under Mac (and has some side-effects, that I want to avoid).

I already tried to build a bundle with mkbundle, but mkbundle doesn't work correctly under Mac.

I should add, that I use GTK.

What is the easiest way to build a compleley independent app under Mac? Is there any good tutorial? Is there a good tool, that could help?

Comment: I should add, that the program uses GTK.

Comment: Edited the title to better reflect what you are actually trying to do.  Removed conversational style.  Added note about GTK (but didn't add a tag.  If you get a solution to the rest of it, but not the GTK problem, you should ask a separate question).

Comment: @Merlyn: If you edit my post, please don't remove important information. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to remove the word Mac from the title.  Was still in your tag, though, so I guess it wasn't completely removed ;)

Comment: This question desperately needs a workable answer. I'm starting a bounty on it.

Answer (score 4):

[Ask Miguel (December 9 2010 blog post)](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Dec-09-1.html)

MonoMac: we just released MonoMac 0.4 and we are now adding support for creating self-contained application bundles that developers can redistribute themselves or even submit to the Apple AppStore for MacOS.

MonoMac has been a lot of work, mostly, due to popular contributions. There is a nice emerging community of new contributors to Mono that has sparked in the last few weeks.

Comment: If I don't want to build an application specifically for Mac, and instead want to use GTK#, is it still possible to bundle self-contained applications with MonoMac?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try macpack?

http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications

Comment: Yes, this creates a app-directory. That is fine, but it doesn't include the mono runtime in my project. So it's unfortunately only half the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use mkbundle in the linking of mono assemblies to produce a "portable app" with no requirement on installing the runtime.

http://www.mono-project.com/Linker